# Share a selected item across applications in Android

Tags: android, sharing, cross-application

I would like to have two applications, app X and app Y.  X where a user can select from list of choices (perhaps a list) and Y then uses the selected choice of X upon start-up.

The reason I need this design is because the choice in X needs to persists even if the user clears data of Y.

Any suggestions on how I can do this on Android?

Comment: What do you mean by "clear data of Y"?

Comment: If the user clear Y's data, then next time they launch Y, the choice made in X should still be available.  The choice would be lost after the data is cleared if I had the selected item saved in Y.

Comment: Couldn't you use an Intent for this? http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just write to a public file in the device internal memory (using XML, for example). [More information](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesInternal).